# No module named <app_name>

Tags: python, django, django-channels

So, I made a chat app using django-channels in a separate project and now I am copying it into the main project.

This is what is happening. when I run `./manage.py runserver`

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f695c1cfde8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 40, in inner_run
    self.channel_layer = channel_layers[DEFAULT_CHANNEL_LAYER]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    self.backends[key] = self.make_backend(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 48, in make_backend
    routing=routing,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.router = Router(self.routing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/routing.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.root = Include(routing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/routing.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.routing = Router.resolve_routing(routing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/routing.py", line 75, in resolve_routing
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import channel routing %r: %s" % (routing, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import channel routing 'website.routing.channel_routing': No module named myWebsite
```

**I know this is some error with django not recognising my module , but in other places it's recognising so why not here**

The culprit code, the reason why I am stuck here for 2 days :

**website/website/routing.py**

```
from channels import include
from myWebsite.routing import websocket_routing, custom_routing


channel_routing = [
    # Include sub-routing from an app.
    include(websocket_routing, path=r"^/chat/stream"),
    include(custom_routing),
]
```

**website/myWebsite/routing.py**

```
from channels import route
from .consumers import ws_connect, ws_receive, ws_disconnect, chat_join, chat_leave, chat_send


websocket_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),

    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),

    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]


custom_routing = [
    # Handling different chat commands (websocket.receive is decoded and put
    # onto this channel) - routed on the "command" attribute of the decoded
    # message.
    route("chat.receive", chat_join, command="^join$"),
    route("chat.receive", chat_leave, command="^leave$"),
    route("chat.receive", chat_send, command="^send$"),
]
```

**Later I added this in website/myWebsite/__init.py__ :**

```
default_app_config='myWebsite.apps.MywebsiteConfig'
```

**website/website/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myWebsite',
    'django_countries',
    'social_django',
    'channels',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'
```

#### The directory structure :

```
website
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── myWebsite
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── backends.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── consumers.py
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
~~ SNIP ~~
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routing.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── static
 ~~ SNIP ~~
│   ├── templates
 ~~ SNIP ~~
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
└── website
    ├── config.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── routing.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

#### So as you can see well above I do have the `__init__.py` in *website/myWebsite* directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It has stalled my work for the last 2 days as I have tried it all.

#### Thanks

### Update As per comments

**New website/website/routing.py**

```
from channels import include
import sys
from myWebsite.routing import websocket_routing, custom_routing


print(sys.path)
channel_routing = [
    include(websocket_routing, path=r"^/chat/stream"),
    include(custom_routing),
]
```

**website/website/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ~~ SNIP ~~
    'channels',
    'myWebsite',
    'django_countries',
    'social_django',
]
```

Since neither of it help so reverting to the original code

Comment: can you change the order of the apps, move that `channels` in apps above all your apps ? try if that helps

Comment: Your import in website/website/routing.py is maybe the problem?  Try `import sys; print(sys.path)` before the import sttement to check that python looks for `myWebsite` in the correct place.

Comment: @rrmerugu

It didn't work

Comment: @HåkenLid
It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Why is there an `__init__.py` in the main directory? None of my Django projects do.

Unless my understanding of these things is wrong —which is entirely possible—  that would be turning `website` into its own module. That would change the absolute path you're using in `website/website/routing.py` to `website.myWebsite.routing`. Yuck.

You could update the absolute path in the import, but honestly, I'd just nuke the file and not turn the active directory into a module.

Comment: I got a suggestion from one of my friends regarding pythonpath , he said that it might be something with that cause iPython does recognise myWebsite as the module but django doesn't .

See the screenshots [Here](https://ibb.co/jomco5)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the utils.py file

I found this error when I used shell on my friend's recommendation.

It popped up when I executed this `from myWebsite.routing import websocket_routing, custom_routing`

and there was no error while just executing `import myWebsite`

Here are the screenshot :

https://ibb.co/m8zQ85

https://ibb.co/eAY7MQ